# Better notation for $A\mapsto\chi_A$ and a question about the elements of $\{0,1\}^X$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, notation

I have two questions that come from the same exercise so I put together in this question. I have an exercise that say

> $f:\mathcal P(X)\to \{0,1\}^X$ and $A\mapsto\chi_A$. Show that $f$ is bijective.

**First question**: I understand what the exercise is asking but the notation used, specifically the part $A\mapsto\chi_A$, seems terrible to my eyes.

I understand that a characteristic function $x\mapsto \chi_G$ map $1$ or $0$ depending if $x$ is an element of $G$ or not. But then we have that $\chi_A(A)=0$ because $A\notin A$.

I understand that the notation $A\mapsto\chi_A$ want the sequence of zeros and ones of some subset $A\subseteq X$ through the function $\chi_A(x)$ for all $x\in X$ (we can infer this because any $f(A)\in\{0,1\}^X$).

Then my question is, there is a better notation for this situation?

**Second question**: if $X$ is countable I understand that we can interpret it elements as a sequence, if $X$ is finite we can interpret the elements as vectors or $|X|$-tuples.

But, how we must interpret the elements of $\{0,1\}^X$ if $X$ is uncountable? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you are confused about the mapping $A \mapsto \chi_A$. The "domain elements" of this mapping are not "elements of $A$", but rather, elements of $\mathcal{P}(A)$. So, for example, $\chi_A(A) = 1$, because $A \subseteq A$.

Comment: @DavidWheeler Elements of $\mathcal P(X)$, like $A$, are in the domain of $f$, not of $\chi_A$.  The domain of $f$ is $\mathcal P(X)$; the domain of $\chi_A$ is $X$.

Comment: My bad, up too late at night. You are correct, sir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure you do understand the notation; you write "$x\mapsto \chi_G$" and "$\chi_A(A)=0$", but neither of these really make sense.

- The function $f:\mathcal{P}(X)\to \{0,1\}^X$ takes elements of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ and produces elements of $\{0,1\}^X$.
- Elements of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ are subsets of $X$, and elements of $\{0,1\}^X$ are functions from $X$ to $\{0,1\}$.
- For a subset $A\subseteq X$, recall that the element $\chi_A\in\{0,1\}^X$ is the function $\chi_A:X\to\{0,1\}$ defined by
  $$\chi_A(x)=\begin{cases}
  1&\text{ if }x\in A\\
  0&\text{ if }x\notin A
  \end{cases}$$
- The exercise states that the function $f$ sends an element $A\in\mathcal{P}(X)$ to the element $\chi_A\in\{0,1\}^X$. In other words, $f(A)=\chi_A$.

Personally, the only thing I would change about the notation in the exercise is that I would write "$f(A)=\chi_A$" instead of "$A\mapsto \chi_A$", but other than that I think the notation used is both standard and intelligible.

As for your second question, the elements of $\{0,1\}^X$ are just the functions from $X$ to $\{0,1\}$, and I'm not sure I see a particular need to interpret them any other way.

Comment: Most of this answer is what I would have written.  The one thing I'd add is that, as far as I can see, the only reason for writing $f(A)=\chi_A$ rather than $A\mapsto\chi_A$ is that the symbol $\mapsto$ seems to be the main source of the OP's confusion. For someone who is comfortable with $\mapsto$, the only change I'd make in the quoted exercise is to replace "and" by a colon, to make it explicit that "$A\mapsto\chi_A$ is intended as the definition of $f$.

Comment: Ok, my problem is that I dont have a definition of the characteristic function very clear (I dont see it in the book of the exercise), and wikipedia is not of help. I will appreciate if you can put here someone or let me some link.

Comment: @Masacroso: I've added some more details that should be helpful to you. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Ok, I understand completely. There is an unique characteristic function for any set. Thank you very much.

Comment: May I ask why is it even certain, that $\chi_A$ represents every point in the set $\{0,1\}^X$? Can't there be functions in there which are different than $\chi_A$? Let's say for example the function which maps every second element of $X$ onto $0$ and the other ones in between on $1$ or so...

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{ 0, 1 \}^{X}$ denotes the class of all maps from $X$ to $\{ 0, 1\}$; so the map $A \mapsto \chi_{A}$ defined on the class of all subsets of $X$ lies in $\{ 0, 1 \}^{X}$.

For each $A \subset X$, we can assign exactly one characteristic function, namely $\chi_{A}: X \to \{ 0, 1\}$; hence we may define the function $f: A \mapsto \chi_{A}: X \to \{ 0, 1 \}^{X}$.

Can you now clear up your questions?

Comment: I understand what you says, but there is not a better notation for $A \mapsto \chi_{A}$?

Comment: @Masacroso: the notation $f:A\longmapsto \chi_A$ and $f(A)=\chi_A$ are both very standard and completely interchangeable. I'm not sure what you expect.

Comment: @Masacroso I guess you may get the notation wrong :). If you still want to get a feeling about it, please be referred to my answer again.

Comment: @GudsonChou, thank you very much, I understand now completely. I was just doing my own interpretation of $\{0,1\}^X$ and the symbol $\mapsto$.